# How to prevent access of protected members

Tags: java, jar, protected

I have a class

```
package java.util;

public class xyz {
    void method(){
        ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<>();
        al.elementData = new Object[10];
        System.out.println(al.elementData);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        xyz z = new xyz();
        System.out.println("hello");
        z.method();
    }
}
```

when I try to run it I get an exception like below

```
objc[6598]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.util
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:662)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:761)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:495)
```

Suppose at company FOO we developed and shipped a jar file called foo.jar to clients. Now the clients can access protected members in com.foo.pack.TestClass, just by adding it in classpath, and declaring `package com.foo.pack;` in a class, like in the example above `xyz.class` I am able to access `elementData` of ArrayList.java.

My question is, how to prevent that access or usage or visibility of company FOO's protected members.

Comment: Welcome to java programming.  You can not prevent access to protected members.  Only private prevents access and that will not work for what you want.

Comment: An approach  I see is, not enabling them to load the classes of company through the client/exploiter/user's classloader. They can code and compile the code but they can never run it since they won't be able to load the classes. But the question is how to implement this approach!

Answer (score 0):

Seal the packages in the manifest, and sign the JAR file.

Comment: if you sign, then you can't load them

Answer (score -1):

By reflection you can access and even modify private members. And that's very common (Just check the [`@Autowired`](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-autowire) annotation for dependency injection).

I am not sure what are your trying to achieve, but if you want to prevent inverse engineering from your clients, try to obfuscate your code with some tool.